# Specifications of a motor which will light an led (momentarily) from hand-spinning?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, generator, hobbyist

**EDIT:** I feel I might have placed the emphasis wrongly in my original question so I'll try to revise it here.

In the video cited the demonstrator [can be seen spinning a small "hobby" motor with her fingers and lighting an LED](https://youtu.be/KOd6-PFkEy8?t=64). Can anyone suggest what the specifications of that motor might be ? Or an actual motor which I could buy online. (I have tried reading the model number off the screen but no joy ;-). I am also interested in more general information but that's the main thing I would like to know. Thanks

---

In [this video](https://youtu.be/KOd6-PFkEy8) an LED [is lit](https://youtu.be/KOd6-PFkEy8?t=64) by spinning the rotor of a "hobby" electric motor.

I have tried doing just that with a number of motors and not seen the same effect (tried with LED in both polarities).

A couple of the motors used were ones I had lying around and I've no idea of their specs. Another one was [this one the specifications of which can be seen on the 'specifications' tab of this web page](https://www.jaycar.co.nz/6v-9-000-rpm-dc-electric-motor/p/YM2712).

The description of the motor used in the video and provided by the video maker is "Small hobby motor, 6-12 volts" but I suspect that's an insufficiently detailed description of the motor used to ensure the effect shown is seen.

What are the specifications of a motor that would work as shown ?

Secondarily, what is a useful text which outlines all parameters of such motors and what their effect would be when using the motor as a generator ?

Comment: Are you looking at permanent magnet motors or motors with field windings ? Look at motors with inbuilt gears so that you can rotate the shaft slowly and the armature will rotate fast enough to generate enough voltage.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I take your point about the gears and that would certainly seem to be one way forward however the "hobby motor" shown in the video is, I'm almost certain, just a plain old motor with any gearing so I am still quite interested in knowing what that is. The project shown in the video would, due to the small windmill in use with it, not generate enough torque to turn a geared motor .... this is speculation on my part as I'm not knowledgeable in the field but I do think that's so. Thanks again for your thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

A motor is a backwards generator. So flip all the specifications around.

That motor has a no-load RPM of 13500RPM when 6V is applied. So for you to get it to produce 6V, no-load, you must spin it at 13500RPM. Spin it at 1/3 the speed and you will produce 1/3 the voltage. Can you pull that off manually? Probably not. Pick a motor that spins the lowest possible speed at the highest possible voltage.

You are going to a bigger motor, since bigger motors have the tendency to run slower for the same voltage. If you have 6 diodes to make a 3-phase rectifier, an outrunner motor is your best bet (it is a brushless motor so has no brushes to rectify the current in the coils to DC. It will end up as 3-phase AC so you need a 3-phase rectifier).

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's really useful, I wasn't aware of the straightforward relationship between the "acting as a motor" and "acting as a generator" specifications you described. I take your point about a bigger motor but I am still quite interested in how the demonstrator appears to have a very straightforward "hobby motor" and is able to produce enough voltage to light, momentarily, the LED.

Comment: I don't know about the motor in the video, but honestly, you have no idea where the motor came from. It could have been designed to run off a much higher voltage or whatever and still look the same from the outside. What LED are you using?

Comment: To me it looks like a coreless motor, which has no cogging so it is easy to spin at high speed. Perhaps similar to [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Micro-Mini-16mm-Big-Coreless-Motor-DC-5V-5800RPM-Large-Torque-DIY-Tattoo-Machine/264820681403?hash=item3da88aeabb:g:jgAAAOSwsnhfHuZ7)?

Comment: If you need a small low rpm motor, [here's one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-12V-24V-Micro-18MM-18MM-Square-Motor-Large-Torque-6-Pole-Rotor-Small-DC-Motor/264788901759?hash=item3da6a5ff7f:g:IawAAOSwcRdfAyn~) that only needs 263rpm per volt (should light a white LED at ~900rpm)